# Excel cell blank space check in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am reading an excel file and the contents are then to be stored in DB. The problem is space check in excel sheet column. Some of the columns are spaces and for them DB values will be null. I have a put check for null value while reading cells but somehow it isn't working as expected.

Code

```
if (workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 12].Value != null)
store.WeeklyOff = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 12].Value.ToString();
if (workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value != null)
store.OpenTime = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value.ToString();
if (workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 14].Value != null)
store.CloseTime = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 14].Value.ToString();
```

In the above snippet I have put null value check for each cell. The issue is column 12 is also spaces and for this check works fine i.e. `if` condition is false and it moves to next statement but from column 13 onwards the null check isn't working. While debugging I can see the `null` for column 13 & 14, still `!= null` check isn't validated and the code in the `if` statement gets executed and I get null pointer exception. I have tried a lot many other things for null check but nothing isn't working as expected. Struggling from last 1 day but nothing seem to be working. All the variables are defined as `String`. Please advise.

Comment: Weird question: if you're just reading the data from the spreadsheet, why aren't you using Oledb?

Comment: Also you're going to run into trouble if there is no `Cell` value at that index.  You would need to run a null check on that: `if (worksheet.Cells[rowIterator, 12] != null)`

Comment: Thanks for the input. But since I am doing this for the first time, I searched for some tutorials, and did as what I understood. Will look for Oledb and try as suggested. Anyways I tried as suggested above removing .Value but still the same. It's still executing condition inside If and I get null pointer exception.

Comment: If I knew what line it referred to, I could tell you more about what's going on.  Here's some detail about using OLEDB to read from Excel: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB

Comment: Thanks for the link. I too found this after you suggested. Lemme try with this quickly.

Comment: Are you sure that you have columns beyond 12th one in excel ?

Comment: @Peck_conyon Yes.There are 23 columns in all and 2500 rows to be read.  Out of these 23 columns, a few doesn't have any value i.e. they are spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var x = string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value;
if(value != null)
{
  store.OpenTime = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value.ToString();
}
```

or

```
Type t = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].value.GetType();
if (t.Equals(typeof(string)))
{
    var x = string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value;
    if(value != null)
    {
      store.OpenTime = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eminem. But I have already tried this. By using above it again throws null pointer exception as workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value.ToString() is null. So this time null pointer exception is thrown at If condition.

Comment: How about assigning it to a value before. See changed answer

Comment: Then use try and catch blocks and inside catch (NullReferenceException) assign  the values as you want  may be an empty string for such places

Comment: Or maybe the .ToString() is failing. If it passes the if statement check and fails on the assignment line then the issue has to be converting the value to a string. Gaurav check the type of the values in the if statement. Type t = typeof(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value);   ... or something similar

Comment: Yes Eminem's suggestion also need to check

Comment: @Eminem Tried the edited answer but now getting null pointer exception at var x statement. Just noticed one thing. While debugging condition is marked "false", still it's executing statement inside "if". I mean when I place my cursor at != while debugging,  it reflects value as false, which means value is null. But still the next statement is executed. Now going to try typeof as suggested.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202855/condition-false-but-code-inside-the-if-statement-executed

Answer (score 0):

```
    try
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value.ToString()))
        {
            store.OpenTime = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException)
    {
       store.OpenTime = SomeValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This seem to be working but after 3-4 rows, getting Null Reference Exception again. Also not sure if using try/catch for 23 columns and 2500 rows will be a good bet. I understand try/catch is expensive and should be used as the last resort.